# Permissions that applies only in specific context? Keycloak?

Tags: security, spring-security, permissions, microservices, keycloak

Let's imagine that I need to develop something like Discord, there will be Roles and Permissions that apply in the context of a guild. Now I need to implement a system that has similar functionality.

How would you approach the implementation of such a system?

I'm a bit confused, I was planning to use Spring Framework and Keycloak as SSO. I don't see how it can be applied for permission management.

Also it is worth to mention that the client is SPA in a web browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create different roles for each guild (like `guild-a:moderator`, `guild-a:member`, etc.): there is an admin API which you can call from your spring application to [create new roles](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/21.0.0/rest-api/index.html#_roles_resource) when a new guild is created. You can even programmatically [assign this roles](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/21.0.0/rest-api/index.html#_role_mapper_resource) to some users using this API.

Another way of proceeding would be handling users roles assignment across guilds in your Spring application and exposing a REST API for it. You can then define a Keycloak "mapper" which would query this API during user login process (after the user is successfully identified but before the access token is issued) and write user's guilds roles matrix in a private claim. I did something like that (set a private claim with the result of a REST call in a Keycloak mapper) in [this project](https://github.com/ch4mpy/user-proxies).

Comment: I researched a bit, and found that all roles and permissions probably will contained in one access token. Isn't it bad? Just in case user have 20 guilds, than, probably, it will have big overhead.

Comment: For a user member of 20 guilds and granted with 5 roles in each, it would be a 100 strings. It should fit in a token. As long as all roles are fetched in one go, there should not be any noticeable perf difference compared to a user with one role in a single guild (but it should perform much better than a solution where roles are fetched from a DB for each request in the authentication converter)

Answer (score 0):

I've used Keycloak in multiple projects and it's pretty awesome once you get the hang of it. Besides regular roles, Keycloak also supports role attributes and groups with their own attributes. So, for example, you can have an "admin" role with cool attributes like `canDeleteUser: true` or `canCreateUser: true`. These attributes work like key-value pairs and you can customize them to do whatever you need. Oh, and don't forget about groups! You can create groups, add users to them, and assign roles to groups. That way, every user in a group automatically gets the assigned roles.

One of the best things about Keycloak is how easy it is to use. It's powerful, secure, and takes care of all your security worries. Plus, there are tons of tools and modules available that make it even more convenient to work with Keycloak. If you're using Java, you're in luck because there's excellent documentation on how to integrate Keycloak with Java. It'll definitely make your life easier.

**In your case I would use Realm Roles as roles and Role Attributes as permissions.**

Hope you find this helpfull

Comment: Yeah, but important point in my question is guild, roles can be assigned in specific guild. And if I understood right, Keycloak roles are only global for realm.

Comment: They are global for real, but they are not assigned to every user in realm upon creation, you need to assign them and as I previously said you can assign them to groups inside a realm, so they can be specific only for a group